# Divs overlapping, cant position footer properly and general problems with positioning

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to get my footer div to stick to the bottom of the page, I dont want it fixed to scroll with the windows, just at the bottom of the document. It just seems to float ontop of my main content. I'm also having trouble getting the divs to line up, they all seem to have padding on the top and bottom. have I missed something in my markup?

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>The Frag Factory</title>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="includes/images/tffLogo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="nextLan">
        The Next LAN is on April 21-24th in
        </br><span>00d.00h.00m.00s</span>
    </div>
</div>
</head>
<body

<div class="navContainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Next Lan</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Sponsers</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Servers</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="sliderContainer">
        <img src="includes/images/sliderImage1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <vertical around themdiv class="mainContainer">
        <h1>MAIN CONTENT</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor, turpis faucibus ultrices mollis, nisl lectus fermentum orci, pulvinar vehicula neque metus vel leo. Praesent semper ullamcorper dolor, quis scelerisque neque venenatis quis. Vestibulum lacinia ut dolor ac fermentum. Pellentesque ornare facilisis ultrices. Donec vel purus eleifend, euismod metus in, faucibus sem. Nullam nulla odio, tristique sed velit vitae, pretium feugiat nibh. Sed a odio leo. Nullam eget enim pulvinar magna volutpat scelerisque eget nec est. Quisque sagittis tincidunt orci. Suspendisse ac erat ut turpis luctus euismod et eget dolor. Duis cursus, erat sed condimentum venenatis, purus urna sodales augue, vitae viverra purus augue sed tortor. Nullam adipiscing dapibus ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBar">
        <center><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor, turpis faucibus ultrices mollis, nisl lectus fermentum orci, pulvinar vehicula neque metus vel leo. </p>
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
    <div id="footerContainer">
        THIS IS A FOOTER
    </div>
</footer>

</body>




</html>
```

And my CSS

```
body{
    font-family: helvetica;
    letter-spacing: 0.09px;
    color: #717171;
    background-image: url("includes/images/dark_mosaic.png");
    display:block;
}
h1{}
h2{}
h3{}
p{}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

/*HEADER*/
.header{
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:75px;
    background-color: #000;

}
.logo{
    float:left;
}
.logo img{
    height:70px;
    width:auto;
}
.nextLan{
    float:right;
    color:#36B627;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.nextLan span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    vertical-align: center;
}

/*NAVIGATION*/
.navContainer{
    background-color: #535353;
    width:900px;
    height:25px;
    margin:0 auto;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    top:-9px;


}
.navContainer li{
    display:inline;
}

/*SLIDER*/
.sliderContainer{
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.sliderContainer img{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
}

/*MAINCONTENT*/


.container{
    width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;


}
.mainContainer{
    width:680px;
    background-color: #000;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
.sideBar{
    width:170px;
    background-color: #D66767;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
/*FOOTER*/

#footerContainer{
    position:absolute;
    height: 180px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    left:0;

}
```

Comment: For your footer problem, try: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ read that too :) i am using that too actually works :)

Comment: That's a lot of divs.  Why not use tables?  Some people just seem terrified to use them, and they coul dmake some of this work a lot easier.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Tables should only be used for tabular data. Hence the name.

Comment: @TylerH - Sometimes you gotta use a crowbar instead of a hammer.  If tables make your job easier, then you're a fool to shun them just because you're not using tabular data.  I use tables for extensive GUI creation, because it makes lining up your fields as easy as pie.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I disagree. You're not a fool for shunning them, instead you are lazy for using them when you shouldn't.

Comment: @Th0rn0 First of all, your HTML is not valid. `<div>` tags and content do not go in the `<head>` section. All content (including headers) must go in the `<body>` section of your document. Use `<head>` for meta information (information about the document) like Title, any CSS links, scripts, etc.

Second of all, your `<br>` tag is incorrect. It either needs to be just `<br>` for HTML5 or `<br/>` for XHTML. You shouldn't ever be using `</br>`.

Comment: @JohnnyBones it also makes your code very inaccessible and will destroy your seo ratings

Comment: @Th0rn0 
Finally, you have some weird stuff going on: You have a <center> tag in your HTML (you should use CSS instead), and it's not even closed. Also the line `vertical around themdiv` doesn't even make sense to me; it's certainly not valid HTML. I'm guessing this is a major typo you didn't mean to insert.

Comment: @Pete - That's not a concern, I design for an Intranet with C#/ASP.Net so we don't need SEO.

Comment: @JohnnyBones hahaha, that explains everything - you called it design!

Comment: @Pete - I'll call it whatever they want as long as they keep paying me $140K/year.  ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I worked through your HTML, which had several errors/invalid HTML. Instead of trying to explain everything, take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f77Zk/).

The main issue you had was that you needed a wrapper around everything BUT the footer, and then set its height to 100% with a margin-bottom of -180px (the height of your footer). You also needed to remove the absolute positioning of your footer, it was not needed.

Update: I have taken a bit more time and found you a better solution that hopefully clears up all of your problems. The footer I previously mentioned will keep it at the bottom of your content, but not necessarily the bottom of the page. The best way to make a footer is to make the html and body both 100% in height, the container 100% in height (with a min-height in your case to prevent the footer from "eating the page" when it is not maximized) and a negative top-margin on the footer, equivalent to its height. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f77Zk/1/) is an updated demo of this in action. I also have updated the below code to match the demo. If you have anymore questions feel free to ask.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>The Frag Factory</title> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="includes/images/tffLogo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="nextLan">
        The Next LAN is on April 21-24th in
        <br/><span>00d.00h.00m.00s</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navContainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Next Lan</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Sponsers</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Servers</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sliderContainer">
    <img src="includes/images/sliderImage1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="mainContainer">
    <h1>MAIN CONTENT</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor, turpis faucibus ultrices mollis, nisl lectus fermentum orci, pulvinar vehicula neque metus vel leo. Praesent semper ullamcorper dolor, quis scelerisque neque venenatis quis. Vestibulum lacinia ut dolor ac fermentum. Pellentesque ornare facilisis ultrices. Donec vel purus eleifend, euismod metus in, faucibus sem. Nullam nulla odio, tristique sed velit vitae, pretium feugiat nibh. Sed a odio leo. Nullam eget enim pulvinar magna volutpat scelerisque eget nec est. Quisque sagittis tincidunt orci. Suspendisse ac erat ut turpis luctus euismod et eget dolor. Duis cursus, erat sed condimentum venenatis, purus urna sodales augue, vitae viverra purus augue sed tortor. Nullam adipiscing dapibus ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
</div>
<div class="sideBar">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"/>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor, turpis faucibus ultrices mollis, nisl lectus fermentum orci, pulvinar vehicula neque metus vel leo. </p>
</div>

</div>

<footer>
    <div id="footerContainer">
        THIS IS A FOOTER
    </div>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body{
        font-family: helvetica;
        letter-spacing: 0.09px;
        color: #717171;
        background-image: url("includes/images/dark_mosaic.png");
        display:block;
        margin: 0;
    }
    h1{}
    h2{}
    h3{}
    p{}

    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }

    /*HEADER*/
    .header{
        margin:0 auto;
        height:75px;
        background-color: #000;

    }
    .logo{
        float:left;
    }
    .logo img{
        height:70px;
        width:auto;
    }
    .nextLan{
        float:right;
        color:#36B627;
        text-align: center;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-top: 6px;
    }
    .nextLan span{
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        vertical-align: center;
    }

    /*NAVIGATION*/
    .navContainer{
        background-color: #535353;
        width:900px;
        height:25px;
        margin:0 auto;
        line-height: 25px;
        text-align:center;
        top:-9px;


    }
    .navContainer li{
        display:inline;
    }

    /*SLIDER*/
    .sliderContainer{
        margin:0 auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    /*MAINCONTENT*/


    .container{
        width:900px;
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 750px;
    }
    .mainContainer{
        width:680px;
        background-color: #000;
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
    }
    .sideBar{
        width:170px;
        background-color: #D66767;
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    /*FOOTER*/

    #footerContainer{
        height: 180px;
        margin-top: -180px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000;
        width:100%;
        min-width: 900px;
    }
```

Comment: If the user has lots of errors/problems, why take the route of "I fixed your problems but I'm not going to explain how or why they were problems"? How should the user learn this way?

Comment: I explained his main problem, that his actual question was about (the footer). The rest of his issues were HTML syntax errors, which he should be able to see comparing his code to what I placed in my answer.

Comment: The footer was only one of three parts to the actual question, if you look at the title. And sure, he can see what's different and how to fix *this exact document* so that it works, but you haven't explained *why* the errors in his code are errors; you've only said that they *are* errors. This is not very helpful to him in the long-run, and not helpful at all to other people with similar problems (since they won't have the *exact* same document as this user). Here you're providing a fix, but it's an [XY Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: Thanks for the input guys,

I'm not a master HTML coder as you can see...

I've re jigged my code but I can't seem to get my footer to display right to the edges of the screen, it has a border on the left and right. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: @Th0rn0 Is your footer div separated from the rest of the document or is it inside any others?

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0` to your `body {}` CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm going to try and compile my comments into an answer here for you:

First of all, much of your `HTML` is not valid. `<div>` tags and content do not go in the `<head>` section. All content (including headers) must go in the  section of your document. Use `<head>` for meta information (information about the document) like `<Title>`, any `CSS` links, scripts, etc. You have some weird stuff going on: You have a  tag in your HTML (you should use CSS instead), and it's not even closed. Also the line `vertical around themdiv` doesn't even make sense to me; it's certainly not valid `HTML`. I'm guessing this is a major typo you didn't mean to insert.

Second, your `<br>` tag is incorrect. It either needs to be just <`br>` (for `HTML5`), or `<br/>` for `XHTML`. You shouldn't ever be using `</br>`. That is the closing version of the tag for `HTML4.01` and previous... let's hope you aren't using HTML4 standards!

For your footer problem, try [CSS Sticky Footer](http://cssstickyfooter.com). It is not at the bottom of your content right now because you are using `position: absolute;`, which removes the footer from the normal flow of your document and places it explicitly at one specific spot in the document, regardless of anything else around, before, or after it.

Here is an updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/LrVU2/)** that attempts to solve your major problems. Note that in JSFiddle links, the `<!doctype>`,`<html>`, and `<head>` tags are removed, since they are not necessary.

Finally, if you have empty elements in your CSS (such as p {} and h1 {}), you should just delete those, rather than leaving them. If you ever end up needing to style those elements, you can always re-add them.

Answer (score -1):

Don't Use unnecessary div and css. check this as reference  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/