# Footer at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, footer

I want the footer to stay at the bottom of the page. Right now, it's at the top... I've posted my html and all my css so you can see. I figured it might be easier to do it that way? I've tried to add containers that stretch the body to the bottom, but it messes with my other containers on the page and makes them fall off way into the top. I need a quick answer because this is due in a week!

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    background:#fff url(images/bg1.png) repeat;
    background-size: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.title {
    width:548px;
    height:119px;
    position:absolute;
    background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
}
#content {
    margin:0 auto;
}
#horizon {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
#stuff {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-left: -500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -125px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 250px;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px dotted #F3DECD;
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
}
```

```html
<body> 
 
    <div id="content">
        <div class="title"></div>

        <div class="navigation" id="nav">
            <div class="item user">
                <img src="images/bg_user.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                <h2>Home</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="aboutshop.html">About the Shop</a></li>
              <li><a href="aboutartist.html">About the Artist</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item home">
                    <img src="images/bg_home.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>How-To's</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="howtojewelry.html">Jewelry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="howtoclay.html">Clay</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item shop">
                    <img src="images/bg_shop.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="jewelry.html">Jewelry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="clay.html">Clay</a></li>
                        <li><a href="digital.html">Digital</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item camera">
                    <img src="images/bg_camera.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <ul>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Questions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
  
        <div id="horizon">
         <div id="stuff">
         <h2> Welcome! </h2><br>
         <p>This is a page that I have created for all my jewelry. This will be updated with new information periodically.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <footer>

        <a href="">
            <img height="32" width="32" alt="'s Deviantart" src="deviantart.png">  
        </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">
            <img height="32" width="32" alt="'s Think Jewelry Page" src="facebook.png"> 
        </a>

    </footer>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Divs overlapping, cant position footer properly and general problems with positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481755/divs-overlapping-cant-position-footer-properly-and-general-problems-with-positi)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of every question with "sticky footer" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply set a div with a position of absolute. It would look something like this:

html:

```
<div id='footer'></div>
```

css:

```
#footer{
  height:45px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:grey;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fixed footer:

**HTML**

```
 <footer>
     ...
 </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The footer will always be visible in the viewport at the bottom of your page, check out this [codepen.](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/NPPEqY)

If you are looking for a sticky footer approach check [this](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/bNNmQr).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
footer
{
 position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a sticky footer that is always present at the end of main content, I’ve always found using a wrapper containing a negative push div (set as the same size as the required footer) is a simple, yet the most solid approach.

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -150px;
}

.push {
  height: 150px;
}

footer {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #900; /*red */ 
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Main Content</p>
            <!-- -->
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>Footer Content</p>
            <!-- -->
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

See codepen example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaPRQb

Simply change the push div and footer heights to be the desired height (in my example 150px) and the wrapper's bottom margin to be a negative of that height (ie. -150px in my example)